# .jpg image error "Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x52 0x49)"

Tags: eog

Whenever i  click on image to see,  this  error  pops up:

> Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x52 0x49)

i'm not able to see  all the  image. please can someone help me to  fix this  issue?

thank you .

Comment: You can check the actual file type by running this command `file [file.jpg]`. We need to know if this is really a jpg file or not.

Comment: A quick google search returns `"if the file starts with "0x52 0x49", then it's a .webp image. Just replace the file name extension from 'jpg' or 'jpeg' with 'webp'"`

Comment: 0x52 0x49 suggests WebP (although not definitive). That's `RI` as first bytes of file. WebP starts with [RIFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Interchange_File_Format). It could be other file formats as well.

Comment: @SorenA If it's a image, that's generally true, but further checks should be made. If it's WebP bytes 8-11 should be `WebP`.

Comment: @vidarlo .. sure. Find the file and run `file filename.jpg` on it as sugested by Michael earlier.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `file` command to identify the image format, then rename accordingly:

```
$ file foobar.jpg

foobar.jpg: RIFF (little-endian) data, Web/P image, VP8 encoding, 1024x751, Scaling: [none]x[none], YUV color, decoders should clamp
```

In this case, change the suffix to `.webp`.
Either install gThumb (haven't tried) or open it with an image editing program like "Gimp". On Gimp, go to **File > export** and change the ending to .jpg.

Or if `file` responds with:

```
 foobar.jpg: PNG image data, 358 x 358, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
```

which indicates that the file is actually in PNG format, not jpeg. So I rename the file and open it with:

```
$ mv foobar.jpg foobar.png
$ xdg-open foobar.png
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm having this same issue. I saved an image from Firefox and changing the extension from .jpg to .webp gives me another error.

Could Not Display filename.webp There is no application for "WebP image" files. Do you want to search for an application to open this file? Cancel Search in Software

I click Search in Software but nothing happens.

Solved:
Go to the terminal.
sudo apt-get install gthumb
Next right click the image> Open With Other Application
Select gThumb as the default application
Perfect! Now I can finally open them and the thumbnail icon changed too. :D